# how to export two columns to csv in python

Tags: python, csv

I am not familiar with how to export the list to the `csv` in python. Here is code for one list:

```
import csv
X = ([1,2,3],[7,8,9])
Y = ([4,5,6],[3,4,5])
for x in range(0,2,1):
    csvfile = "C:/Temp/aaa.csv"
    with open(csvfile, "w") as output:
        writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
        for val in x[0]:
            writer.writerow([val])
```

And I want to the result:

[image]

Then how to modify the code(the main problem is how to change the column?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To output multiple columns you can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) like:

#### Code:

```
import csv

x0 = [1, 2, 3]
y0 = [4, 5, 6]
x2 = [7, 8, 9]
y2 = [3, 4, 5]
csvfile = "aaa.csv"
with open(csvfile, "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerow(['x=0', None, None, 'x=2'])
    writer.writerow(['x', 'y', None, 'x', 'y'])
    for val in zip(x0, y0, [None] * len(x0), x2, y2):
        writer.writerow(val)
```

#### Results:

```
x=0,,,x=2
x,y,,x,y
1,4,,7,3
2,5,,8,4
3,6,,9,5
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, but could we write this in a loop for x= 0,2...., i mean update writing the CSV file as loop runs

Comment: The answer to your questions is YES.  But I do not understand your questions as to the specifics.

Comment: I mean when x=0, we write the first two columns(x0,y0) and when x=2, we add the next two columns(x2,y2) in the same CSV, etc. In your code, you already knew the number of columns.

Comment: But your variables are named `x0` and `x2`.  This is extremely bad practice if you want to iterate over them as a group.  How about using a `dict` so that you can properly iterate?  Other than that does this answer answer the question you asked?

Comment: ok, I just change the code, could help me modify the code for loop?

Comment: So after I took the time to answer your question, you have changed the question?  Do you think this is reasonable behavior?  How many times would it be OK for you to change the question and expect me to change my answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168161/discussion-between-user6703592-and-stephen-rauch).

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
with open('file.csv') as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    [fout.write(r[0],r[1]) for r in reader]
```

If you need further help, leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with csv files you should really just use Pandas.  Put your header and data into a dataframe, and then use the .to_csv method on that dataframe.  Csv can get tricky when you have strings that contain commas, etc...

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html